# Excel Macro - copy/paste file name in automatized Data entry process

Tags: vba, excel

Perhaps that could really be an easy one to build, but I couldn't find out on the forum, maybe I'm only missing keywords or sintax.
Simple data entry process, I got a master file (it is a report overview from different locations), in which I copy paste cells from about 16 different reports.
Something like this

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="E:\TARANTO.xlsx"
Range("D29").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Overview weekly reports.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("n").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(3, 14).Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllExceptBorders, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Windows("TARANTO.xlsx").Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Overview figures from ASTs weekly reports.xlsm").Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllExceptBorders, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Windows("TARANTO.xlsx").Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Overview figures from ASTs weekly reports.xlsm").Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllExceptBorders, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
'' and so on
```

What I would like to get is to copy the file name of the report into a cell, ideally adding it to the Offset cycle, just like copying another cell.
The result would be for instance:

TARANTO                3                  4             8               9

CROTONE                6                  9             4               4

ETC.

Unfortunately, the location is not mentioned in any cell inside the form, I need to grab exactly the file name every time.
I tried recording also, but of course no action appears on VBE when I attempt to copy the file name manually.
Please any help would be really appreciated.
Have a good day!

Comment: You would be advised to assign some workbook variables and then you could dispense with all the activates and selects. It's not clear from there where you are pasting?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a developer, trying to do my best, I am trying to paste from taranto.xlsm to Overview etc,then I open Crotone.xls and copy to Overview, then I open Roma and so on.I just would like to add to this cycle the file name to specify for which location data comes from and pasting it into the cell I want

Comment: But where exactly should the file name appear? Because all your references are to active cells it's hard to see exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: This I will manage by myself playing with the Offset, I just need the line after Taranto is open, that copies the name and paste it even at the end of the copy from Taranto.Every time I open a new report I start with Range("D29").Select to stop the Offset cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the name of the active workbook you can use:

Activeworkbook.Name

To write this into a cell just put:

```
Range("A1").value = Activeworkbook.Name
```

This will input the file name (including the extension) into the cell.

Comment: I would like to paste the file name as text into a cell, shall I just add this line and then continue pasting as I was doing?

Comment: @Diego Trec - `Range("A1").Value2 = Activeworkbook.Name`. Change A1 with whatever cell you need the name in.

Comment: @jivko thanks, but doing this way, the active workbook is the Overview, not Taranto, then in the cell A1 I will get Overview etc instead of Taranto, right?

Comment: @DiegoTrec you could set the workbook as a variable to be used later.

Comment: @Hocus apologies, I'm not a real developer, could you please edit the code you posted?

Comment: @DiegoTrec I would spend some time googling "VBA Variables" or something similar, that being said as you know the file names (you are opening them manually) you could just add to your code

    Range("[Cell to add it to]").Value = "[Worksheet name]" after you activate your sheet

Comment: @Diego Trec - `Dim wbkTaranto As Woorkbook Set wbkTaranto = Workbooks.Open Filename:="E:\TARANTO.xlsx"`. Then you can reference `wbkTaranto` instead of `Activeworkbook` and you'll be sure it's the correct workbook. You can use a similar approach when referencing worksheets.